# page transition is not working with swup js

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition, page-transition

I have 2 pages as of now. What I am doing is, I am trying page transition and I am using below plugin [swup](https://swup.js.org/). Now my issue is page transition is not working when I click on the menu.

I added menu like `/index` and `/about` in href and my URL is 
`http://localhost:8080/example/index` and when I click on menu then I am getting `object not found` and URL is showing `http://localhost:8080/about`

can anyone help me out with this issue?

**header.php**

```
<header>
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="/index">Index</a></li>
<li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</header>
```

**Index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <?php include('assets/include/header.php');?>
  <div id="swup" class="transition-fade">
    <h1>This is homepage</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swup@latest/dist/swup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**about.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>About Document</title>
  <link href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <?php include('assets/include/header.php');?>

  <div id="swup" class="transition-fade">
    <h1>This is Aboutpage</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
  </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swup@latest/dist/swup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.transition-fade {
    transition: 0.4s;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  html.is-animating .transition-fade {
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

**main.js**

```
import Swup from 'swup';
const swup = new Swup();
```

Comment: Hey! Just like to ask if you ever found a solution for this? am facing the same issue in Django as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your links are wrong and basically lead to a pages that don't exist.

Change your menu links to:

```
<li><a href="/example/index">Index</a></li>
<li><a href="/example/about">About</a></li>
```

Comment: example is my root folder.